# symfony2 access private files as admin user

Tags: php, symfony, assets

In my Symfony2.3 project, i have a frontend website and a backend. The backend is secure by security.yml file and only role_admin user can acces backend.

Want i want now is only admin users can download pdf files stores in assets.

Is there a way to do this ?

now, all visitors can access my pdfs files by url link.

Do i have to move this pdf to another folder? or use an htaccess maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store these files in a location that is not directly accessible through your webserver. (i.e. **not** in the `web` folder or one of it's subfolders)

Then create a controller/action that checks for the permission to download (i.e. a certain user-role) before serving the file.

Read the documentation chapter **[Serving Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files)** for a quick overview of how you can serve files in symfony2.

Comment: thanks a lot. Does it make sense if i store pdfs into app/Resources folder? And what is the way to serve pdf content htrough a controller action?

Comment: Sure you can create a subfolder in `app/Resources` to store your files. just don't name it `public` as the contained files would then be picked up by the `assets:install` command and be copied/symlinked to the `web` folder which is not desired. I have added a link to the documentation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, it's a big help for me !

Answer (score 0):

Add a role, something like ROLE_ACCESS_PRIVATE ASSETS and assign it to the admin user. Do the check for that permission in the code like any other.

Edit: This is assuming, of course, that a controller stands in the way of these files.